# K9 web protection installation: active connection is required

Tags: windows-10, internet-connection, blocking, parental-controls, web-filtering

I have tried to install K9 Web Protection on my windows 10 x64 machine several times. But every time after pressing install in the following picture, It says `Not Responding`

[image]

And finally I get the following error

[image]

I have checked everything and I'm sure that internet connection is active.
I can even enter http://www1.k9webprotection.com/ without any problem.
would you please help me to find the cause of this problem and fix it?

My ping results based on instructions [here](http://www1.k9webprotection.com/support/kb/K9104.html)

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @Ramhound clearly there's only 1 question. Why do I get this error when trying to install while I am actively connected to the internet

Comment: I copied and pasted the "too broad" explanation.  The part of the explanation that applies to your question, is the following, **a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.**  I specifically never said you were asking multiple questions

Comment: @Ramhound there's no more detail I want to install the app but it says I'm not connected to the internet while I am sure I'm connected

Comment: [I believe you need to configure your firewall to always allowed `C:\Program Files\Blue Coat K9 Web Protection\k9filter.exe`](http://www1.k9webprotection.com/support/kb/K9104.html)

Comment: Have you contacted K9 support, this is a configuration issue on your end, likely caused by the use of a proxy or a misconfigured firewall setting.  In any event unless you can provide more detail diagnose information it will be difficult to tell you what to change.  The K9 website is absolutely abysmal.  Have you confirmed this software even supports Windows 10?  *My research indicates it might not.*  I assume you have also done [this](http://www1.k9webprotection.com/get-k9-web-protection-free)

Comment: You being able to ping Google doesn't show your proxy or firewall still isn't blocking the client from contacting the Activation domain for K9

Comment: @Ramhound in fact i have installed it once and then uninstalled last night. it worked once on this system and have been uninstalled normally so I should be able to reinstall it. Also when the program isn't installed on my machine, i don't have that `C:\Program Files\Blue Coat K9 Web Protection\k9filter.exe ` on it to configure the firewall to always allow it